# Android - Gerar Apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Como eu faço para gerar apk no Android Studio?

- 1.0 - Fui em Build -> Build APK.
- 1.1 - Ao concluir coloquei no smartphone e deu o seguinte erro: Existe um problema de análise do pacote.
- 2.0 - Fui em Generate Signed APK criei as chaves e foi gerado o arquivo APK.
- 2.1 - Ao concluir coloquei no smartphone e deu o mesmo erro como o anterior.

Como posso proceder corretamente?

Comment: O APK está sendo gerado corretamente. Então não é esse o problema.

Normalmente esse problema de análise de pacote é erro do projeto. Ou no JAVA, no XML, no Manifest, etc.

Tente criar um projeto modelo, aqueles templates prontos que já vem no Android Studio, gere o APK, e verá que está fazendo o procedimento correto de geração de APK. Em seguida, poste aqui os arquivos do projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumindo que você está querendo gerar o APK para produção (para distribuição), você precisa antes, gerar as chaves em Build>Generate Signed APK...

Este link pode ajudar [Preparar para o Lançamento](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html)

Se ainda não é a versão definitiva, não use a opção Build APK, mas sim o menu Run para rodar o APK no emulador ou num aparelho conectado ao USB. Depois que estiver tudo pronto e você gerar as chaves de segurança, deve funcionar.